# I have written this code to get the value of my slider when i drag it but it is not working. Can you tell me why?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, slider

I have used slider as a fragment and calling it in main activity on clicking a button. I want the value of my slider to show on dragging for this i have also written some code but it is not working. Can you tell me why?

I am giving my code:

To call slider as a fragment in main activity:

```
val brush:ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.brush)
        var isOpen:Boolean = false
        var drawingView:DrawingView? = null
        drawingView?.setSizeForBrush(20.toFloat())
        brush.setOnClickListener() {

                supportFragmentManager.commit {
                    setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    add<fragment_brush>(R.id.fragment_container_view)
                    isOpen = true
                }
                    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                        supportFragmentManager.commit {
                            add<fragment_brush>(R.id.fragment_container_view)
                        }
                    }
            }
```

To get value from the slider:

```
var slider:Slider? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        slider = view?.findViewById(R.id.brushSlider)
        slider!!.addOnChangeListener(Slider.OnChangeListener { slider, value, fromUser ->
            Toast.makeText(context,"Value is $value",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried logging it instead? Dragging a slider produces a lot of updates, and you're displaying a Toast for each one - with `LENGTH_LONG` too! You'll be watching Toast popups for days. The Toast message doesn't dynamically update or anything, it's just fixed text

Comment: Yes! i tried to print it in logcat but it shows nothing